# How to set default tick params in python/matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like all of my plots to have ticks that point inside rather than the matplotlib default of outside. So I am looking for a way to set this using plt.rcparams()

For each plot, at the moment, I am doing:

`ax.tick_params(direction='out')`

But this only works for a single plot. Any idea how to set this with a default plot style at the top of the script or through plt.style.use()?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reading the [rcParams](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/customizing.html?highlight=xtick.direction#customizing-with-matplotlibrc-files) helps:

```
plt.rcParams["xtick.direction"] = "out"
plt.rcParams["ytick.direction"] = "out"
```